# Nodejs lightweight framework

Tags: node.js, systemjs

Looking for a framework in Node.js

1. Which is lightweight [low memory footprint]
2. Support Rest, with request and response headers http request
3. Supports Fibers
4. Supports local npm packages
5. Lightest weight testing framework

Not sure i should be adding the npm individually 
OR 
use a well maintained library(framework) like systemJs or any other, please Suggest.

Answer (score 1):

For REST go with express

For test suite I'd recommend mocha chai sinon and super test

If your backend is proxying requests u also might want to use nock

Use Istanbul for coverage

This is the standard business approach, I am tech lead at large company

Comment: Questions that are completely off-topic for stack overflow like this one should not be answered.  Instead, you should vote to close.  If you aren't acquainted with what is on-topic, you can read here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic